# Next Meeting vs. the NEXT Meeting

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

My organization meets the same day (3rd Thursday) every month. On our web site, I am displaying rotating announcements with details for "April Meeting", "May Meeting", and so on. I want to add headers so it is clear to everyone which meeting is next, but I am stuck on the word NEXT.

I am looking for a two-word title to express the meeting that is happening within the next thirty days, and another two-word title to express the meeting that is happening a month AFTER that.

Today is April 11th. In Slot A is the April Meeting. Do I label it "This Meeting", "Next Meeting", or what?

In Slot B is the May Meeting. Do I label it "Next Meeting", "Upcoming Meeting", or what?

Answer (score 2):

How about "This Month's Meeting" and "Next Month's Meeting"? I know it is more than the two words but it is simple and makes sense.

Or if two words are a must, why not simply put "April's Meeting" and "May's Meeting"?

Comment: Because they rotate. Next month it will be May and June. I was looking for titles that did not change, in addition to the titles specific to the event.

Answer (score 0):

> **next** *adjective*
>   1 (of a time) coming immediately after the time of writing or speaking.
>   1.2 (of an event) occurring directly after the present one in time, without anything of the same kind intervening.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/next)

There's always some ambiguity about "next". It could be the one coming up (definition 1 - immediately after the time of writing), or the one after that (definition 1.2 - the April after the 'present' April; the meeting after 'this' meeting).

To avoid ambiguity, consider using an absolute term such as "April 2019" or "April 2020" etc, and avoid the word "next" altogether.